# How can I manually set the IP a domain name resolves to without using the hosts file?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosts, dns-server

On my Windows server, `example.com` resolves to `1.1.1.1`. A software I use resolves `example.com` expecting `1.1.1.1`, but I need to modify this for the domain to resolve to `2.2.2.2` instead.

Usually, I would use the hosts file, however the software checks the file and doesn't run if `example.com` is in the hosts file. So, I need another method to solve the problem.

I currently use Google's public DNS. If I must run my own DNS server modified to make `example.com` resolve to `2.2.2.2`, that's not a problem, but I'd only use this as a last resort.

How can I solve my problem, preferably without a custom DNS server?

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have control of the domain example.com to make DNS changes, and you cannot edit the hosts file for reasons stated above...then your only other option would be to create a local nameserver to assist you.

Comment: It sounds pretty impractical, though, since I'd just be setting it up to resolve one domain.

Comment: well the hosts file is designed exactly for this purpose. is there some configuration within your software so that it just runs independently from any changes in the hosts file?

Comment: Smells like bypassing some copy protection - if the software CHECKS the host file for the specific entry, then obviously the provider of the software is protecting against "simple" redirects.